# Woocommerce memberships restrict content

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, membership, restriction

It should be quite simple, but I just can't restrict content for non-members via the metabox. Setting it like on the attached picture won't restrict it neither for the members with Regular membership nor for the anonymous visitors.

[image: my meta box]

Answer (score 0):

Do you should go in "woocommerce" -> "Membership" -> "Membership Plan". case not have a plan, create, and select the restriction in "Restrict Content".

[image: 1]